# Why am I getting "ImportError: No module named pyramid.config"

Tags: python, windows, pyramid, pylons

I am using python 2.7.5 on windows and I have followed these [directions](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/narr/install.html#installing-chapter) for the windows python 2 section to the letter.

I found 2 other questions on SO with the same problem but they were both on linux and the top answers were not helpful

the only thing I can see that might have gone wrong is when I ran

```
C:\env> scripts\easy_install pyramid
```

I got a warning that said :

"WARNING: The C extension could not be complied, speedups are not enabled. Plain-Python installation succeeded."

Could that be the problem?

Comment: Could you try running the script using

C:\env> C:\Python27\python.exe scripts\easy_install pyramid

Comment: it didn't work with the first argument "C:\Python27\python.exe" probably because easy_install isn't a python file

Comment: Could you include the cmd output when you try and run the command?

Comment: C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file 'scripts\easy_install': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: I'm pretty sure scripts should be capitalised S, so Scripts\easy_install.exe pyramid

Comment: That warning, The C extension could not be complied, speedups are not enabled. Plain-Python installation succeeded. isn't a problem, just means there is no c compiler available to the cmd

Comment: I got the same output when  i capitalized the S in scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem.  My virtual environment was correctly set up, I just needed to run my code through the version of python found in the scripts folder of my virtual environment.

The python file you are trying to run can be found anywhere on your local machine as long as it uses python from that environment, for example

```
C:\anypath\onlocalmachine> C:\env\Scripts\python.exe helloworld.py
```

I was making the mistake of putting my python file in the virtual environment and attempting to run the following WRONG code

```
C:\env> helloworld.py
```

I thought that I was supposed to be working entirely within the virtual environment
Thanks for the help in the comments rebelious